# Avoid Redirect::back with mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, mockery

I'm just trying to write some tests about Laravel 4 password reminder:

I want to avoid this being executed:

```
case Password::INVALID_USER:
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
```

And I tried:

```
Redirect::shouldReceive('back')->once();
```

And I'm getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function with() on a non-object

I found how to adapt the mockery when the call has parameters, but not how to avoid this issue.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but i still want to know how to do it with mockery if someone knows.

The error when i do:

```
$this->call('POST', 'password-reminder', $data)
```

was:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Cannot redirect to an empty URL.
```

Thats why i was trying to avoid the Redirect::back call with mockery, but you can avoid it doing this:

```
$this->call('POST', 'password-reminder', $data, array(), array('HTTP_REFERER' => '/password-reminder'));
```

Really the url that you write on HTTP_REFERER doesnt matters for testing.

Find on : http://alexsears.com/article/testing-redirectback-laravel

Answer (score 0):

your first test should work with one small adjustment.

```
 $fakeRedir = Mockery:mock('Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse');
 Redirect::shouldReceive('back')->once()->andReturn($fakeRedir);

 //you could do additional assertions on your $fakeRedir here
 // $fakeRedir->shouldReceive('with')->once()->with(/* argument asserttions here*/);
 $result = $yourInstance->yourMethodUnderTest();
 $this->assertEquals($fakeRedir,$result);
```

You have mocked the request facade to receive back correctly but by default the mocks return null unless otherwise directed usind the shouldReturn method.